# Generic UTC DateTime serialization in Apache Ignite

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I am working with Ignite .NET thin client.

In ignite documentation it is wriiten that to support platform interoperability we should store DateTime in UTC format. I can also store DateTime value in local format but data could not be viewed in DBeaver in this case.
When I put data in the cache or get data from the cache I have to manually convert DateTime values from UTC or local format. For the conversion I use DateTime.SpecifiyKind or DateTime.ToUniverslaTime, DateTime.ToLocalTime methods like in the example below.
Is there any generic solution to automatically convert all DateTime values beetween UTC and local formats instead of writing custom logic for each property of each model in application?
Perhaps it could be some kind of generic DateTime serializer.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    var configuration = new Core.Client.IgniteClientConfiguration
    {
        Endpoints = new List<string> { "127.0.0.1" },
        BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration
        {
            Serializer = new BinaryReflectiveSerializer { ForceTimestamp = true }
        }
    };

    using (var ignite = Ignition.StartClient(configuration))
    {
        var person = new Person { FirstName = "John", Birthday = new DateTime(1990, 08, 17) };

        var cacheConfiguration = new CacheClientConfiguration("people", new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(Person)));

        //person.Birthday = person.Birthday.ToUniversalTime();
        person.Birthday = DateTime.SpecifyKind(person.Birthday, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                
        var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>(cacheConfiguration);
                
        cache.Put(0, person);

        var personFromCache = cache.AsCacheQueryable().Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        //personFromCache.Birthday = personFromCache.Birthday.ToLocalTime();
        personFromCache.Birthday = DateTime.SpecifyKind(personFromCache.Birthday, DateTimeKind.Local);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignite does not provide such an automatic conversion. Some options are:

- Implement `IBinarizable` interface and perform conversions there:

```
    public class Person2 : IBinarizable
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public void WriteBinary(IBinaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteTimestamp("Date", Date.ToUniversalTime());
        }

        public void ReadBinary(IBinaryReader reader)
        {
            Date = reader.ReadTimestamp("Date").Value.ToLocalTime();
        }
    }
```

- Use serialization attributes to hook into the process:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        
        [OnSerializing]
        internal void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
        {
            Date = Date.ToUniversalTime();
            Console.WriteLine("OnSerializing");
        }

        [OnSerialized]
        internal void OnSerializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
        {
            Date = Date.ToLocalTime();
            Console.WriteLine("OnSerialized");
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
        {
            Date = Date.ToLocalTime();
            Console.WriteLine("OnDeserialized");
        }
    }
```

- Use properties with backing fields and perform conversion in getter and setter

All of that requires individual handling for every property, though - I don't have better ideas without reflection and/or code generation.